# Cannot Send data from Java Client to Python Server

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp

I'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17440933/5460216) to send data from a Java client and receiving it on a python server. The data sent is a simple string of length 10 but I'm not able to receive it on server side. It shows a blank output for received data even when the connection is established properly. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654514/communication-javaclient-with-pythonserver) question and so I've reprogrammed my server to first receive 2 bytes and then receive the string but it's not working. Can anyone explain? I've put some comments to explain the output.

> Server.py

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
print "Socket Created..."
s.bind((str(socket.INADDR_ANY), 2609))
print "Socket bound to INADDR_ANY with port 2609..."
s.listen(5)
print "Socket listening for connections..."
print "Waiting for client to connect..."
(c, remote_addr) = s.accept()

print "Connection From" + str(remote_addr) + " accepted"
rec = 'pppppppppppppppppp'

print 'rec = ' + rec               #Properly prints the initialized string
print 'lenght is ' + str(len(rec)) #prints length = 18
print "Receiving Data..."
leng = c.recv(2)
print "Data received..."
print leng                         #Does not print Anything

rec = c.recv(1024)

print rec                          #Does not print Anything

print 'lenght is ' + str(len(str(rec)))  #Length is 0
c.close()
print "Client socket closed..."
s.close()
print "Server Socket closed..."
```

> Output

```
% python Server.py
Socket Created...
Socket bound to INADDR_ANY with port 2609...
Socket listening for connections...
Waiting for client to connect...
Connection From('192.168.43.7', 39100) accepted
rec = pppppppppppppppppp
lenght is 18
Receiving Data...
Data received...


lenght is 0
Client socket closed...
Server Socket closed...
```

Comment: Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: @thatguy : python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the rest of your code on the sende side is unknown, I cannot identify the problem for sure, but there may be two possible reasons I can imagine:

### Sender side

You use the code as stated in your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440795/send-a-string-instead-of-byte-through-socket-in-java/17440933#17440933). If you do not receive anything, this may indicate that the `OutputStream` is bufferedand nothing is send, **yet**, although you called `write(...)`. Try to `flush()` it and see if you receive something.

### Receiver side

In Python 3 `recv` returns a bytes object as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv):

> The return value is a bytes object representing the data received.

In Python 2, you get a string, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#module-socket):

> The return value is a string representing the data received.

Now, as you send your strings from a Java client, which encodes in `UTF-8`, you should decode the bytes or string again at the receiver side with `data.decode('utf-8')` to get a Unicode string.